# Display sorted data in php with mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to echo the format like this from MySQL data.

```
Samsung: note 5, note 6, note 7
Apple: iphone 6, iphone 7
```

I have the following table

```
----------------------------
    brand   |     product   |
-----------------------------
    Apple   |     iphone 6  |
-----------------------------
   Samsung  |      note 5   |
-----------------------------
   Samsung  |      note 6   |
-----------------------------
   Samsung  |      note 7   |
-----------------------------
    Apple   |     iphone 7  |
```

How can I echo them? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show what you've tried and the specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick solution using our MySQL wrapper (most wrappers have similar functions):

```
$ba=array();
$dh->Query("select brand,product from YOUR_TABLE_NAME");

for ($i=0;$i<$dh->NumRows();$i++) {
    list($brand,$product)=$dh->fetchRow();
    if (!isset($ba[$brand])) $ba[$brand]=array();
    $ba[$brand][]=$product;
}
foreach ($ba as $b=>$pa) {
    print "Brand $b: ".join(",",$pa);
}
```

You can display them easily from generated array $ba.I have provided a simple dump example.